# how to send image to another activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Bitmap bitmap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img);
    i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream);
            byte[] byteArray = bStream.toByteArray();

            Intent anotherIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, anotherActivity.class);
            anotherIntent.putExtra("image", R.drawable.img);
            startActivity(anotherIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: pass the path of the image and retrieve the image using the path in another activity.

Comment: write your file to file system (sdcard) and pass the path to another activity, in next activity read the file and delete the local path copy if that is no longer needed.

Comment: its a drawable you can access it in another activity.

Comment: Try base64. for encode and decode image.

Comment: If it's a static resource, you don't have to pass anything and you can just access it in another activity as @Raghunandan said. If your case is different, you can try to serialize this data with Parcelable or something similar and then pass it to specified activity. I don't recommend this approach, because it would be inefficient. Simply save this image on disk and pass path to the image as String like it was already said.

Answer (score 0):

You can send byteArray to other activity using intent.

```
Intent anotherIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, anotherActivity.class);

anotherIntent.putExtra("image", byteArray);

startActivity(anotherIntent);
```

Now you must be receive this bytearray to another activity.

```
Bitmap bmp;

byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```